# Display carriage returns from text area in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

On a .aspx page I have a textarea. Someone enters 'one', then a carriage return, 'two'.

The data is stored in a Sql Server database.

On another page I retrieve that data and display it in a gridview in a BoundField.

On the screen it appears as:

one two

It was entered as:

one

two

What do I have to do to get data entered in textareas with carriage returns, to display as it was entered when it is not subsequently being displayed in a textarea?

Comment: Have you checked if the carriage returns are persistent in data when displayed in the gridview?

Comment: You don't see anything in the data in the gridview. I have found the answer I think. If I have a label in the gridview which is displaying the data - writing myLabel.Text = key[3].ToString().Replace("\n", "<br />";